# Twilio Programmable Chat API - Updating member channel role

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Is it possible to update role of a member within the channel by providing Role friendly name instead of Role SID?

The reason I'm asking this is because I would like to avoid storing any generated identifiers on my end and to keep only friendly names.

In this particular case I would like to pass friendly names for Channel and Member Identifiers(Path Variables) as well as RoleSid (Form Body)

[Member Role API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/members?code-sample=code-add-a-member&code-language=Java&code-sdk-version=7.x#update-an-existing-member) that i'm refering to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I would recommend that you store the generated role identifiers. Friendly names are not enforced to be unique, so the best way to refer to a role is by it's Sid.

If you are really against storing the Sids (and I don't see why you would be), you could always [list all the roles](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/roles) and filter by the friendly name that you are looking for, then use the Sid from that resource in the request to update the role.

Let me know if that helps.